# Why are my radio buttons not visible?

Tags: android, html, tablet

This is my markup:

```
<div id="step6" class="step">
  <div id="glazing_instructions">Please select your glazing type from these options:</div>
  <input type="radio" name="Glazing" value="GAPC" onclick="glazing_change_glass(this);" />Premium Clear Acrylite (<a onclick="window.open('/static/glazing/glazing.html#pca','null','width=730,height=620,scrollbars=yes,resizeable=yes')">learn more</a>)
  <input type="radio" name="Glazing" value="GACC" onclick="glazing_change_glass(this);" />Conservation Clear Acrylite (<a onclick="window.open('/static/glazing/glazing.html#cca','null','width=730,height=620,scrollbars=yes,resizeable=yes')">learn more</a>)
  <input type="radio" name="Glazing" value="GAR" onclick="glazing_change_glass(this);" />Reflection Control Acrylite (<a onclick="window.open('/static/glazing/glazing.html#crca','null','width=730,height=620,scrollbars=yes,resizeable=yes')">learn more</a>)
  <input type="radio" name="Glazing" value="GAOM" onclick="glazing_change_glass(this);" />Optium Museum Acrylite (<a onclick="window.open('/static/glazing/glazing.html#oma','null','width=730,height=620,scrollbars=yes,resizeable=yes')">learn more</a>)
</div>
```

On a regular browser the radio buttons show up, but when I view the page on my Android browser, the radio buttons are not being shown. You can still click where they would be and one gets selected.

How can I get the radio buttons to render correctly?

EDIT: It turns out the radio buttons are rendering, they are just a very light gray color that is very similar to the background they are on. How can I get them to render like they would in a browser?

EDIT2: Once I click a radio button to be selected, the other ones are visible.

Comment: Have you tried in a different browser on your Android device (e.g. Google Chrome)? Are you using the default view of the input buttons, or are you adding some special styling that maybe disable viewing the result? What CSS are you using on the elements?

Comment: No, because I need them to show up on the default browser. I am not adding any styling to the buttons.

Comment: And it's only happening on your site? Not on others?

Comment: Yeah because I have a background color similar to the default radio button color